# Edit Mimetypes.rdf

Tags: delphi, firefox, mime-types, associate

Are there any sources out there that show how to add an entry to the Mimetypes.rdf file that firefox uses. I want to associate a mime-type with my app that I have written in delphi and thought this would be the easiest way to do this.

Thanks,
Gail

Answer (score 1):

No, the best way to do this is to register with the operating system and Firefox will pick that up.